# scalaz Iteratees from scala Iterator

Tags: scala, scalaz

I edited the code below as I believe I had been combining the IterV objects incorrectly on top of the `iter.next` issue.

I'm experimenting with `Iteratee` in scalaz and I am wondering why the following does not work. Here is what I have:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
import IterV._

implicit val iteratorEnumerator = new Enumerator[Iterator] {
  def apply[E,A](iter: Iterator[E], i: IterV[E,A]): IterV[E,A] =
    if (iter.isEmpty) i
    else i.fold(done = (acc,input) => i, 
                cont = k => apply(iter, k(El(iter.next))))
}

/* probably incorrect
val iter = Iterator(1,2,3)
println("peek(iter) " + peek(iter).run)
println("peek(iter) " + peek(iter).run)
*/

def peekpeek[E]: IterV[E, (Option[E],Option[E])] = 
  for (a <- peek; b <- peek) yield (a,b)
def peekheadpeek[E]: IterV[E, (Option[E],Option[E],Option[E])] = 
  for (a <- peek; b <- head; c <- peek) yield (a,b,c)

peekpeek(Iterator(1,2,3,4)).run
peekheadpeek(Iterator(1,2,3,4)).run
```

This returns:

```
res0: (Option[Int], Option[Int]) = (Some(1),Some(2)) 
res1: (Option[Int], Option[Int], Option[Int]) = (Some(1),Some(2),Some(3))
```

Where I was expecting `(Some(1),Some(1))` and `(Some(1),Some(1),Some(2))`.

I suspect this has to do with `iter.next` being side effecting. What's the best way to deal with that?

For comparison, [this](http://scalaz.googlecode.com/svn/continuous/latest/browse.sxr/scalaz/example/ExampleIteratee.scala.html#18457) taken directly from the source code examples from the scalaz [web site](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/) works properly:

```
implicit val StreamEnumerator = new Enumerator[Stream] {
  def apply[E, A](e: Stream[E], i: IterV[E, A]): IterV[E, A] = e match {
    case Stream() => i
    case x #:: xs => i.fold(done = (_, _) => i, 
                            cont = k => apply(xs, k(El(x))))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured this out. It seemed to be primarily due to `El` using a by name parameter, which recomputes `iter.next` - as well as how I initially called the computation incorrectly with two different `peek(iter).run`. I rewrote the enumerator to first assign `iter.next` to a *val* (and also made it tail recursive in the process):

```
implicit val iteratorEnumerator = new Enumerator[Iterator] {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def apply[E,A](iter: Iterator[E], i: IterV[E,A]): IterV[E,A] = i match {
    case _ if iter.isEmpty => i
    case Done(acc, input) => i
    case Cont(k) => 
      val x = iter.next
      apply(iter, k(El(x)))
  }
}
```

Then:

```
def peekpeek[A] = 
  for (a1 <- peek[A]; a2 <- peek[A]) yield (a1,a2)
def peekheadpeek[A] = 
  for (a1 <- peek[A]; a2 <- head[A]; a3 <- peek[A]) yield (a1,a2,a3)
def headpeekhead[A] = 
  for (a1 <- head[A]; a2 <- peek[A]; a3 <- head[A]) yield (a1,a2,a3)

peekpeek(Iterator(1,2,3)).run
peekheadpeek(Iterator(1,2,3)).run
headpeekhead(Iterator(1,2,3)).run
length(Iterator.from(1).take(1000000)).run
```

would return this:

```
res13: (Option[Int], Option[Int]) = (Some(1),Some(1))
res14: (Option[Int], Option[Int], Option[Int]) = (Some(1),Some(1),Some(2))
res15: (Option[Int], Option[Int], Option[Int]) = (Some(1),Some(2),Some(2))
res16: Int = 1000000
```

Answer (score 2):

You're correct about iter.next causing side effects. I think that the question boils down to what is the difference between a Stream and an Iterator. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282754/what-is-the-difference-between-a-view-and-a-stream) has relevant information.

Answer (score 2):

Iteratees are lazy. Side-effects (iterator) and laziness do not mix. Maybe this will do the right thing:

```
implicit val iteratorEnumerator = new Enumerator[Iterator] {
  def apply[E,A](iter: Iterator[E], i: IterV[E,A]): IterV[E,A] =
    iter.foldRight(i)((x, y) =>
      y.fold(done = (acc, input) => y,
             cont = k => apply(iter, k(El(x))))
    )
}
```

Then again, maybe not. Only the source of foldRight will know. Side-effects are like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid side effects by creating a throwaway iterator of size one:

```
implicit val iteratorEnumerator = new Enumerator[Iterator] {
  def apply[E,A](iter: Iterator[E], i: IterV[E,A]): IterV[E,A] =
    if (iter.isEmpty) i
    else i.fold(done = (acc,input) => i, 
                cont = k => apply(iter, k(El(iter.take(1).next))))
}
```

Comment: That seemed to work at first, but then I think the iterator never really moves as `def firstTwo[E]: IterV[E, (Option[E],Option[E])] = for (a <- head; b <- head) yield (a,b)` returns `(Some(1), Some(1))`